# How to remove one 'document' by 'ID' using the Official C# Driver for MongoDB?

Tags: c#, .net, mongodb, mongodb-.net-driver

Can someone please show me, if there is a better way to remove one `document` from MongoDB using the [Official C# Driver](https://docs.mongodb.org/ecosystem/drivers/csharp/) than what I have below-

```
var query = Query.EQ("_id", a.Id);
database.GetCollection<Animal>("Animal").Remove(query);
```

This code works, but seems *too much work* to me. The "Save" command for example- takes an instance and updates it. I want something like- `Remove(item)`.

**Remarks:** I'm trying to use the official driver of C# rather than [NoRM](https://github.com/atheken/NoRM) or [Samus](https://github.com/samus/mongodb-csharp) which seems out of date.

Answer (score 35, accepted):

That's the way you do it. I'm sure you know this, but if you want to put it on one line you could combine it so you don't need to define a query variable:

```
collection.Remove(Query.EQ("_id", a.Id));
```

Comment: I'm trying to remove by a field other than _id, and I tried Query.EQ("FieldName", value) but it didn't work. How should I do that?
Actually, your code gives the same error either : "only classes can be mapped currently."

Comment: I just realized that I used a linq query, not  the Query.EQ() above, and I guess that was the problem because it worked when I changed it to Query.EQ() query. Thanks for your help.

Comment: This is not longer the answer, MongoDb Driver has changed significantly, this is no the correct answer: collection.DeleteOne(a => a.Id==id);

Answer (score 27):

## The Simplest Way

Remove a `document` from a `collection` for **C# MongoDB Driver** (v2.0 or later)-

```
collection.DeleteOne(a => a.Id==id);
```

Or-

```
await collection.DeleteOneAsync(a => a.Id==id);
```

Answer (score 23):

If the [id] is string, you must use ObjectId instance explicitly.

```
var query = Query.EQ("_id", ObjectId.Parse(id));
```

Comment: I was having a problem that this answer fixes. Thanks. Upvoted.

Answer (score 2):

My ASP.NET Core MVC controller's action accepts Id as a string parameter. Then I parse it and use the result in the DeleteOne() statement:

```
[HttpPost]
public IActionResult Delete(string id)
{
    ObjectId objectId = ObjectId.Parse(id);
    DbContext.Users.DeleteOne(x => x.Id == objectId);
    return null;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
var filter = Builders<BsonDocument>.Filter.Eq("_id",ObjectId.Parse(id));
var x = data.DeleteOne(filter);
```

I am using this with the current version ( in 2019 ), and it works.

Answer (score 0):

If you only want to delete a `docuement` from a `collection` :

```
public async Task<bool> Delete(string id)
{
    FilterDefinition<YourModel> filter = Builders<YourModel>.Filter.Eq(p => p.Id, id);

    var deleteResult = await _context.YourModelCollection.DeleteOneAsync(filter);

    return deleteResult.IsAcknowledged && deleteResult.DeletedCount > 0;
}
```

And if you want to delete all the `docuements` :

```
public async Task<bool> DeleteAll()
{
    FilterDefinition<YourModel> filter = Builders<YourModel>.Filter.Empty;

    var deleteResult = await _context.YourModelCollection.DeleteManyAsync(filter);

    return deleteResult.IsAcknowledged && deleteResult.DeletedCount > 0;
}
```